# put the value of radio button and checkbox into 1 field in database via php

Tags: php, database, checkbox, radio-button

how to insert the value of radio button and checkbox together into 1 row database..for example the table contains name of menu and the size of the food. The Database table contains food and price..so when we choose which menu we want with checkbox and choose the size of our food use radio button, the value of checkbox and radio button will store in 1 row database...
Please help me find out

this is my code
menu.php

```
<form action="price.php" method="post">

Menu : <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Siomay" name="tile[]">Siomay <br>
    <input type="radio" name="field[]" value="4" />Small
    <input type="radio" name="field[]" value="5" />Large<br>


<input name="confirm" type=submit id="confirm" value='Confirm'>

</form>
```

price.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("project1", $con);

$insert="INSERT INTO menu(name, price) VALUES ('".$_POST['tile']"','".$_POST['field']"')";

if (!mysql_query($insert, $con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con) 
?>
```

Comment: What is the name of the table that you are inserting into?  Are the columns name and price?

Comment: Check your $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");  <--  password ???

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need your name to be an array, so I would first remove the "[ ]" from your "name" attr in your html.

In php, concatenate your two values to make one value and then insert that into the database.  Something like:

```
<?php
$tile = $_POST['tile'];
$field = $_POST['field'];

//concatenate your variables however you want them stored in your db (here it will be tile, field)
$combo = $tile . ', ' . $field;

//connect to db (notice the mysqli function, not mysql!)
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//build query and store result in $result var
$query = "INSERT INTO `tablename` (name) VALUES (" . $combo . ")";
$result = mysqli_query($query);

echo "1 record added";
?>
```

Where (name) will be your column name that you want your concatenated value to be stored.  Obviously, fill in your own information for username, password, db_name etc.

NOTE: It is standard practice now to use mysqli functions (or PDO) and not mysql functions to help protect against sql injections.  Here it is not as relevant, but it is good practice regardless.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like;

```
<?php 
    $size = sizeof($_POST['tile'])
    while($size >= 0) {
      $insert="INSERT INTO menu(name, price) VALUES ('".$_POST['tile'][$size]"','".$_POST['field'][$size]"')";

    $size--;
   }
?>
```